# How Ethereum NFT Protect Artist Work ( How NFT IMMUTABILITY works on BLOCKCHAIN)?

Tags: nft, immutable, immutability

Hi Guys let discuss how NFT Immutable works on ethereum blockchain

I'm new to nft, just created my first one with opensea:) as in image1. My question

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgxB5.jpg

Is my art piece on blockchain now ? and No body can claim it's own or imitate it ? Or I have to pay eth fee to list, that will only make it immutable as in image2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmFYv.jpg

Or it is not immutable (anyone can copy and create it own ) until it is sold to someone as shown in image3??

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQCY3.jpg

Thanks :)